# Why does querySelectorAll('div') return a list of HTMLDivElement but querySelectorAll('div.className') returns a list of Element in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am wondering why is it that when you put a class name to querySelectorAll the type is no longer appearing as HTMLDivElement.

```
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(item => {
    // item type is HTMLDivElement
});

document.querySelectorAll('div.className').forEach(item => {
    // item type is Element not HTMLDivElement
});
```

This means that if I want to change the style it gives an error:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(item => {
    item.style.display = 'none';
});

document.querySelectorAll('div.className').forEach(item => {
    item.style.display = 'none'; // TS2339: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.
});
```

I have found a few ways around this (below), but I am curious why it is even necessary.

```
// Cast all items in NodeList to HTMLDivElement type
document.querySelectorAll<HTMLDivElement>('div.className').forEach(item => {
    item.style.display = 'none';
});

// Cast current item to HTMLDivElement type
document.querySelectorAll('div.className').forEach(item => {
    (item as HTMLDivElement).style.display = 'none';
});

// Only change style.display if instanceof HTMLDivElement
document.querySelectorAll('div.className').forEach(item => {
    if (item instanceof HTMLDivElement) item.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition is here:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L11347

*(permalink to current version in case it moves around later: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/4a7b6dc7497db7847bfa01c2e747fb5e7c200224/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L11347)*

As it seems, they have specialized definitions for known HTML & SVG elements, returning a more specific list in those cases. I'd say your

```js
document.querySelectorAll<HTMLDivElement>('div.className')
```

is the correct solution for other cases.